# Getting The Application User's Data That Belongs To The Pet Was Created

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a one to many relationship between users and pets. I would like people to be able to see the Application User's data that created the pet and put it up for adoption in the pet's detail view. I would also like to retrieve all the pets the user created in the Account/Manage/Index file.

**Different Pet's Model**

```
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
```

**ApplicationUser's Model**

```
public List<Reptile> Reptiles { get; set; }
public List<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
public List<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
```

**ApplicationDbContext**

```
public DbSet<Reptile> Reptiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(r => r.Reptiles)
                .WithOne(u => u.ApplicationUser)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(r => r.Dogs)
                .WithOne(u => u.ApplicationUser)
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(r => r.Cats)
                .WithOne(u => u.ApplicationUser)
                .IsRequired();

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
```

This is how I am currently getting the user which I know it's the wrong way.

```
var applicationUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
reptile.ApplicationUserId = Convert.ToInt32(applicationUserId);
```

I can only get the current user that is logged in data. Not the user that actually created the pet.

**Reptile Model**

```
public class Reptile
{
    public int ReptileId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Reptile's Image")]
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Food Requirements")]
    public string FoodReq { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Habitat Requiremtns")]
    public string HabitatReq { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Recent Checkup")]
    public bool RecentCheckup { get; set; }
    public bool Trained { get; set; }
    public bool Neutered { get; set; }
    public bool Declawed { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Good With Other Reptiles")]
    public bool GoodWithRept { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Good With Kids")]
    public bool GoodWithKids { get; set; }

    
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public int ApplicationUserId { get; set; }



}
```

**Details Page (currently trying to display the user's first name only until I can display the data I need successfully)**

```
    @model PetAdopt.Models.Reptile

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Reptile</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApplicationUser.FirstName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ApplicationUser.FirstName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Age)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Image)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Image)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FoodReq)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FoodReq)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HabitatReq)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HabitatReq)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Gender)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Type)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Size)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Size)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Color)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Color)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RecentCheckup)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RecentCheckup)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Trained)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Trained)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Neutered)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Neutered)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Declawed)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Declawed)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GoodWithKids)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GoodWithKids)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GoodWithRept)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.GoodWithRept)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.ReptileId">Edit</a> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share how you access the current user?

Comment: Sure, just added it.

Comment: So you set reptile.ApplicationUserId when it is created right?

Comment: I think you wanna get `user that actually created the pet`. You might get like `var applicationUser = context.Reptiles.Find(reptileId).ApplicationUser;`.

Comment: Yes, it sets when it is created. I will Try the above code right now.

Comment: FirstName of the user is still blank when I navigate to the details of the pet's page.

Comment: Does the .Find() method automatically give me access to that user in the view from the controller or do I have to assigning to the reptile.ApplicationUser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem is how to get the related entity data. You can use `.Include` method
for example:

```
var user = _context.Reptiles.Include(r => r.ApplicationUser).FirstOrDefault(r => r.reptileId == 1);
```

And you can refer to the document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: I tried your way by doing `var user = _context.Reptiles.Include(r => r.ApplicationUser).FirstOrDefault(r => r.ReptileId == 1);` I also tried matching the reptile.ApplicationUserId to a user in the database like this: `var user = _context.Reptiles.Include(r => r.ApplicationUser).Where(r => r.ApplicationUserId == reptile.ApplicationUser.Id);`, Both ways are still giving me empty data in the pet's details page. @mj1313

Comment: @EnochJohnson Can you show us your Reptile model and your pet's details page codes?

Comment: Reptile model and reptile's details page is up.

Comment: After reading through the documentation and watching this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YucN7Qu_LDs), I figured it out using this code: `            var user = _context.Reptiles.Include(r => r.ApplicationUser).Where(r => r.ReptileId == id).FirstOrDefault();
`